# How can I combine data from two generic lists and assign that amalgamation as the datasource of a DataGridView?

Tags: c#, linq, datagridview, lambda, generic-list

I have two classes, AssignmentHistory and Students. I want to show the contents of AssignmentHistory in a DataGridView like so:

```
List<AssignmentHistory> assignmentHistory = AYttFMConstsAndUtils.AssignmentHistList
    .OrderBy(s => s.StudentID_FK).ThenBy(w => w.WeekOfAssignment).ToList();
dataGridViewStudentHistory.DataSource = assignmentHistory;
```

But the AssignmentHistory class only has a StudentID, not a name; the name is in the Student class. I can get it like so:

```
Student student = StudentsList.FirstOrDefault(s => s.StudentID == studentId);
string fullName = $"{student.firstName} {student.lastName}";
```

(Student.StudentID corresponds to AssignmentHistory.StudentID_FK)

How can replace the ID with the fullname so that it will display in the DataGridView?

### UPDATE

It doesn't seem to want "Include"; I tried "Union" but that didn't work, either:

```
List<AssignmentHistory> assignmentHistory = AYttFMConstsAndUtils.AssignmentHistList
                .Union(AYttFMConstsAndUtils.StudentsList)
                .OrderBy(s => s.StudentID_FK).ThenBy(w => w.WeekOfAssignment).ToList();
```

When I do that, the "s." in the OrderBy doesn't allow any member of either AssignmentHistList or StudentsList.

### UPDATE 2

What I ended up doing, at least temporarily, is creating a third class which combines data I need for this situation from two different generic lists. I loop through the contents of assignmentHistory and, where necessary, get the value I need through code like:

```
Student student = GetStudentForStudentId(ah.studentId);
string fullName = student.FullName;
newClass.FullName = fullName;
```

...etc. Then I simply use that new, amalgamated generic list, comprised of bits and pieces from elsewhere, as the datasource for the DataGridView.

Comment: Are you using WPF or WinForms?

Comment: WinForms, to be sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If student is accessible from/property of AssignmentHistList

```
List<AssignmentHistory> assignmentHistory = AYttFMConstsAndUtils.AssignmentHistList
                                           .Include(x => x.Student)
                                           .OrderBy(s => s.Student.StudentId).ThenBy(w => w.WeekOfAssignment).ToList();
```

this will include all the fields from assignmenthistlist and student

but if not

```
List<AssignmentHistory> assignmentHistory = AYttFMConstsAndUtils.AssignmentHistList
                                       .Include(x => x.Student)
                                       .OrderBy(s => s.Student.StudentId)
                                       .ThenBy(w => w.WeekOfAssignment)
                                       .Select(x => 
            new { Field1 = x.field1, 
                  Field2 = x.field2..... 
                  StudentFirstName = StudentsList.Where(y => y.StudentId == x.AssignmentHistory.StudentID_FK).Select(c => c.FirstName).FirstOrDefault(),
                  StudentLastName = StudentsList.Where(y => y.StudentId == x.AssignmentHistory.StudentID_FK).Select(c => c.LastName).FirstOrDefault(),
                  StudentFullName = StudentsList.Where(y => y.StudentId == x.AssignmentHistory.StudentID_FK).Select(c => c.FirstName + " " + c.LastName).FirstOrDefault()}
.ToList();
```

I

Comment: See my update; maybe I'm doing it wrong, but I couldn't get it to work (no "Include" seems to be available; I also tried it with "Union"

Comment: @B.ClayShannon is it okay if i edit again the answer?

Comment: Gewiss! Porque no?